# GPS app failing to start after boot when targetting API Level 26 (Oreo) update

Tags: android, android-gps

I have gps app on google store which target API version 25. I made some functional update and updated target/compile version to 26 because Google requires that these days. But my background service fails when it try to start after boot. Android studio is not giving any error when I debug. When I change back target version to 25, my app starts fine after boot.

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate();
PowerManager p = (PowerManager) getSystemService(this.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock=p.newWakeLockPowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "tag:DoNotSleep");    
}
```

Android Studio gives a warning on NullPointerException, or on the tag for the following line. But it does not block me build the code. It seems I have to change something on the following line.

```
wakeLock=p.newWakeLockPowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "tag:DoNotSleep");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes

As one of the changes that Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces to improve battery life, when your app enters the cached state, with no active components, the system releases any wakelocks that the app holds.

So if you're depending on a wakelock to keep your service active, it won't.

Comment: Then what I should use now? This is a background service which sends gps location to a server. I want  to run it auto after boot. Wakelock was working nicely for API 25.

Comment: A foreground service, but that will break when you go to Doze.  Nothing other than whitelisting your app from Doze (which must be done by the user) will fix that.